# Calculating expected value from paired values and weights

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I'm very new to *Mathematica*. I just need a quick solution on how to multiply `x` with `y` when a data set is given as

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}
```

where `xi` is the value and `yi` is the weight. So I'm trying to calculate the expected value. How do I do it in *Mathematica*?

---

Thanks all...."Flatten" wouldn't work in this case as it's a huge data set.....thils answer is quite helpful. It's not the prob/stats that I'm new to, but I have absolutely no idea about Mathematica.....

Comment: `Times @@@ list`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I edited your question for better formatting. Please click the edit button to see how it's done, or visit the [help center for more details](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `Dot @@ Transpose[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}]` ?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your list is as follows

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}

Dot @@ Transpose[m]/Total[m[[All, 2]]]

(* 5 *)
```

Comment: +1 Interesting use of `Dot`.   It would be nice if you provided an explanation of the code.

Comment: The denominator (Total[m[[All, 2]]]) yields the effective number of entities, and so division by this factor gives the expected value.

Comment: Equivalent: `Dot @@ MapAt[Normalize[#, Total]&, Transpose[m], 2]`

Answer (score 5):

Using symbolic values and descriptive names for clarity.

Unless the sum of the weights is unity you will have to rescale the weights to get the expected value.

```
n = 4;

data = Array[{x[#1], y[#1]} &, n];

{values, weights} = data // Transpose;

expValue = values.weights/Total[weights]
```

[image]

Equivalently,

```
expValue == Total[Times @@@ data]/Total[weights]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the built-in [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html) directly?

[image]

```
lst = {{x1, w1}, {x2, w2}, {x3, w3}, {x4, w4}};
MovingAverage @@ Transpose[lst]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are just learning about expected value (as I seem to be), the following may seem like a natural way to obtain it.  However, as Bob Hanlon notes, it assumes that the weights are positive integers. This is imposed by `Constant Array[a, b]`, which gives `b` copies of `a`.

```
Mean[Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}]]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

`ConstantArray @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}]` multiplies each value by its weight, giving:

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}}
> ```

which, when flattened is

> ```
> {1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}
> ```

The mean of this **"reconstructed set"** of data will be the expected value, `5`.

Comment: The output should be the expected value

Comment: This assumes (requires) that the weights have integer values

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity, this is another way using higher level built-in  "stats" functions :

Given for example your data:

```
xw = {{x1, w1}, {x2, w2}, {x3, w3}};
```

the corresponding probability distribution is:

```
myDist = EmpiricalDistribution[xw[[All, 2]] -> xw[[All, 1]]];
```

then you can compute

```
Expectation[hello, Distributed[hello, myDist]]
```

> [image]

which is also more simply

```
Mean[myDist]
```

Comment: I would actually consider this the most idiomatic answer of all. :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Actually I would consider this the less idiomatic answer as it is likely to be understood by the broadest range of people ! Isn't it ? ;))